# Error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config, machine.config

I have followed post such as checking machine.config file to remove the extra  and it still does not work. These are the following error message.

> [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>
> - System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings
>     setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +413
> - System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings
>     setting) +51
> - System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.Membership_CreateUser(String
>     applicationName, String userName, String password, String salt,
>     String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean 
>     isApproved, DateTime& createDate, Boolean uniqueEmail, Int32
>     passwordFormat, Object& providerUserKey) +314
> - System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String    username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion,
>     String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey,
>     MembershipCreateStatus& status) +1252
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser() +409
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs
>     e) +221
> - System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,    EventArgs e) +584
> - System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)    +84
> - System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean    includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>     +3804

I'm publishing a web application project using C# in Visual Studio 2013 to a local server using IIS 7. Thank you!

Comment: What is your intended data provider? Can you post the `<entityFramework>` section of your web.config file?

Comment: Is it this?
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

Comment: Yes, that's it, but I don't see any obvious errors. You might be missing the NuGet package for SQL Server Compact Edition. Try running  `Install-Package EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio

Comment: I have installed the package already!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `<entityFramework>` section in your web.config with this:

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the SQL Compact MSI on the server, download from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709

Comment: is on server that i'm hosting?